# App developed by LocalDB: Can Not Open Database Requested By the Login Error

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

-- I've developed a Windows form application  with sql server LocalDB database in Visual Studio (Database is created with visual studio not in SQL Server management studio). Every thing is good in my system but When I copy files (EXE file and .MDF & .ldf files) into another system and execute the program, this error occurs:

can not open database "XYZ" requested by the login localDB. The login failed. Login failed for user XYZ.

-- This is Connection String in APP.config file:

```
connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Initial Catalog=XYZ;Integrated Security=True"
```

-- Also, I have installed SqlLocalDB in that system.

So, what is the problem?!

Update: When I detach the database from the sql server object explorer and try to connect it again same error occurred on my system!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `Integrated Security = true`, you are trying to connect using `Windows Authentication`. Most probably when you do this on a system where the windows login has no authority for given SQL Server, you get this error.
Try using SQL Server authentication, e.g

```
...Integrated Security =False;User ID = <sqlServeruserName>;password=<sqlServerpass>..
```

I would also advise to read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/authentication-in-sql-server)

Comment: I just found that this problem also occurs for me. pls see the updated question.